# Confusion with a BJT datasheet

Tags: bjt

I'm designing an amplifier with a BJT and I decided to use the FMMT495TA (https://www.mouser.es/datasheet/2/115/DIOD_S_A0002833682_1-2542044.pdf) as there will be 0.5A going through the collector. Now, In the datasheet there are two Vce-Ic graphs, one for Vce(on) (page 3/7, figure 1) and other for Vce(sat) (page 5/7, figure 1). As I will be using the BJT in active region, I think that I need to use the graph in page 3, am I correct?. However, that graph doesn't take into account the Ic/Ib parameter, but the Vce(sat) graph does. Why is it? I though that if the BJT is in saturation, the Ic=b*Ib won't take into account.

Comment: Linking to the datasheet, or even posting the relevant snapshots of the graphs would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry @EugeneSh. I have updated the post with a link to the datasheet

Comment: It's a SOT23 transistor with a tiny maximum dissipation. It's meant to be used as a switch ; if you use it in active region (not saturated) to make an amplifier, 500mA max current with any realistic Vce is going to result in a lot more dissipation that it can handle...

Comment: Are you designing a class-A audio power amplifier? Then the output transistor heats a lot all the time, even when not playing any sounds. 0.5A peak in an 8 ohms speaker is a 4V peak voltage and for symmetry, the transistor also has an average of 4V. Then it heats with 0.5A x 4V= 2W. The tiny transistor is rated for only 0.5W maximum. Use a push-pull class-AB amplifier circuit instead.

Comment: I'm using the BJT to drive a few LEDs in parallel so that I can control the light intensity via a potentiometer connected to the base. The current going through the LEDs add up to 500mA max (and I'm not planning to drive them to maximum intensity). Using the Vce(on)-Ic graph in page 3 I get a Vce,max=0.9V and Pmax=0.45W. This way I should be safe, right?

Comment: claimed 500 mW dissipation, aiming for 450 mW dissipation - in your dreams! Check out note 6 and the ambient temperature spec. Word to the wise, derate power by 50% at least, and do actual sums for heat flow, thermal impedance and junction temeprature, for realistic worst case estimates of ambient temperature.

Comment: It has close to 200°C/W chip to board thermal resistance because the legs are very thin. For 0.5W in SMD packages like SOT89 or SOT223 have much better heat transfer due to thicker leads.